# ggplot y axis range ordering not from smallest to largest

Tags: r, ggplot2

Not sure why this is happening it appears to be ordering 1 then 10 then 100, then going to 11?

Here is my code:

```
library(gtrendsR)
library(tidyverse)


keywords = c("SALT Deduction", "State and Local Tax Deduction")
country = "US"
time = ("2010-01-01 2018-12-31")
channel = "web"
trends = gtrends(keywords, gprop = channel, geo = country, time = time)
time_trend <- trends$interest_over_time
head(time_trend)

plot<-ggplot(data=time_trend, aes(x=date, y=hits,group=keyword,col=keyword))+
  geom_line()+xlab('Time')+ylab('Relative Interest')+ theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),legend.position="bottom",legend.text=element_text(size=12))+ggtitle("Google Search Volume")
plot
```

[image: googlesearchvolume]

Comment: Your y-axis is a factor or character column (because of the `<1`) and then it's alphabetically ordered. The easiest way to fix it is to make the column a factor and explicitly set the order of the factor levels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by **@starja** the proper way to solve your issue is formating `hits` as factor. Here a way to do that using `dplyr`:

```
library(gtrendsR)
library(tidyverse)
#Data
keywords = c("SALT Deduction", "State and Local Tax Deduction")
country = "US"
time = ("2010-01-01 2018-12-31")
channel = "web"
trends = gtrends(keywords, gprop = channel, geo = country, time = time)
time_trend <- trends$interest_over_time
head(time_trend)
#Plot
time_trend %>%
  mutate(hits=factor(hits,levels = c("<1",0:100),ordered = T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=date, y=hits,group=keyword,col=keyword))+
  geom_line()+xlab('Time')+ylab('Relative Interest')+ theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),legend.position="bottom",
        legend.text=element_text(size=12))+ggtitle("Google Search Volume")
```

Output:

[image]